# Formulating simple games as Bayesian problems

Tags: probability, bayesian, risk-assessment

Say you are in a game where every win doubles your money and every lose halves. You can walk away any time with the money you have by giving up?

The rules of game is every step a problem is posed and four choices $1$ to $4$ are given and one of them is correct.

Say you have $\$16$ in winnings and you have eliminated $3,4$ leaving with you either to decide on $1$ or $2$ or walk away and 'you think' there is at least $67\%$ possibility of $1$.

Is there a Bayesian decision formula to make 'correct' decisions?

Comment: It's not clear how your statements "'you think' you have at least $67\%$ possibility [I assume you meant probability?] of $1$" and "objectively there is still [a] $50/50$ chance of $1$ or $2$" fit together. Which is it? Do you subscribe to a dual subjectivist/objectivist philosophy of probability where there is both a subjective and an objective probability and they can differ? That would already be somewhat confusing, but then it seems that you even consider that decisions should be based on both of them. I think there's quite a bit to clarify there.

Comment: ok corrected the 50-50. I do not think it is correct.

Comment: I don't see in which sense you corrected it. You took it out of the one paragraph and are still using it in another, now without introducing or explaining it.

Comment: Ok corrected again